# How can I shorten Vector3 without changing it's direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to make an object to follow mouse position, but object is supposed to be closer to the camera.

I tried to normalize rayCastHit Vector and then multiply it. Another thing I did was just dividing rayCastHit Vector by some num. Neither of the methods worked.

```
Vector3 vector = new Vector3(1, 2, 3);
Vector3 vector1 = new Vector3(1, 4, 5);
Gizmos.color = Color.red;
Gizmos.DrawLine(vector1, vector.normalized);

Gizmos.color = Color.green;
Gizmos.DrawLine(vector1, vector.normalized  * 2);
```

[image: That's what I'VE got]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Gizmos.DrawLine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawLine.html) requires a start and end **position**!

You seem to be passing in a start position and a direction.

Either do

```
Gizmos.DrawLine(vector1, vector1 + vector.normalized * 2);
```

Or rather use [`Gizmos.DrawRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawRay.html) instead which takes a start position and a direction

```
Gizmos.DrawRay(vector1, vector.normalized * 2);
```

---

Or in case the `vector` actually is an end position you rather want to do

```
Gizmos.DrawLine(vector1, vector1 + (vector - vector1).normalized * 2);
```

Or accordingly

```
Gizmos.DrawRay(vector1, (vector - vector1).normalized * 2);
```

Comment: Oh crap, that's actually working. Thank u so much, u saved my day!!!